# How do I customize Django Select2 fields?

Tags: django

I started using django-select2 with my forms in one of my apps and I am looking for how to customize the form fields.

For example, with one of the form fields you can select a country, so an icon next to the name of the country would be nice.

Also, maybe present the countries in groups like Popular or by continent.

The [Select2](https://select2.org/) site has some examples that I would like to replicate.

On [django-select2 documentation](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)  is not clear on how to do something like that.

Have you ever tried something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say anything beyond the straightforward default use case of selecting models based on their string representation requires custom code.

The first step in doing so is using [custom JavaScript initialization](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#javascript). This enables you to pass custom [select2 options](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api), like [`templateResult`](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating), to override the rendering of the options.

Grouping is another step of customization. You'll have to override [the `View`](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/blob/master/django_select2/views.py#L11) which generates the data format with some custom code outputting the [select2 grouped data format](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#grouped-data).